# prestashop 1.6 carrier id on product.tpl

Tags: prestashop, carrier

So I want to show a banner " FREE DELIVERY " on product page ( product.tpl ) on ps 1.6.14 , based on selected carrier for this specific product in back office.

Every single product has only one  carrier set in back office.

So basically i need to get carrier id on product.tpl

I played with `{$cart->id_carrier}` with no success - due to empty cart.

Can anyone help me solving this issue ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. Could you please try to explain clearly your demande.

Comment: how can i get carrier id on product template ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add into (or make override): /controllers/front/ProductController.php

```
find: $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
add below: 'carriers' => $this->product->getCarriers(),
```

and then You can use something like this:

```
{if ($carriers[0]['id_carrier']==36)}
    Message!
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite complicated to show a `carrier ID` in a product page.
A carrier is assigned to a product **in order page only**, because it is relative to a customer address (a customer must be logged in, an address saved, a product added to a cart).

You would need to make a custom module or override `ProductController.php`, add some `javascript` and templating code to a product page.

I'd recommend simply to add a banner "Free delivery" manually in a product page to product description.

Comment: To add a banner "Free delivery" manually in a product page to product description is perfect applicable if it comes for 50 - 100 products , but does not sound good for several thousand

Comment: If you have many products you can add it to `product.tpl` with a condition of product category ID or else product data.